# Alternative to initWithNibName

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The tutorial I'm using is outdated (Before storyboards).  It says that initWithNibName gets called when the app loads.  However I've read that that's no longer true.

Also, I'm getting "Expected ';' after top level declarator" for this,

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{


}
```

Which is probably an unrelated problem.

Comment: Please add code for us to help you, or/and explain better your question

Comment: You should have a - in front of id, so it looks like "-(id)initWithNibName..."

Comment: initWithNibName gets called if it's called to initialize. You can initialize without a view controller without a nib by doing MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

Comment: And then in - (id)init{ you would initialize your view controller, probably calling self = [super init]; first thing.

Comment: quantumpotato there's already a "-" in front of id, see the above code.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give a complete answer without more information.  You are correct in that initWithNibName is not called when using storyboards.  Most likely you can remove the initWithNibName method and ignore the code in the tutorial's initWithNibName method as most likely it just initializes a view controller using a xib file (which you probably are not using since it sounds like you set up your project to use storyboards) that was created in interface builder.

Or it might be easier to follow the tutorial if you just remove storyboards from your project and do it the old way (using xib files).  That is probably what I would do.

To follow up with your comment: You could place that code in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    questions=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    answers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [questions addObject:@"some question"]; 
    [answers addObject:@"answer1"];
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else that's initially called once when an app loads?

Comment: Yes, but...  Depending on what the tutorial is doing in initWithNibName, you may not need it anyway.  Can you post the tutorial's completed initWithNibName code?  That would help quite a bit.

Comment: (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        questions=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        answers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        [questions addObject:@"some question"];
        [answers addObject:@"answer1"];
        
    }
    return self;

Comment: I don't think you can put a block of code in comments.  Just a single line as far as I know.  Anyway, you should be able to put the code above into your viewDidLoad method.  I have modified my original answer to add a code block for you.  That should work.